# Pytest parametrize run after the last iteration

Tags: python, pytest, parametrize

When using `@pytest.mark.parametrize('arg', param)` is there a way to find out if the last item in `param` is being run? The reason I'm asking is I want to run a cleanup function unique to that test that should only run after the very last iteration of `param`.

```py
param = [(1, 'James'), (2, 'John')]
@pytest.mark.parametrize('id, user', param)
def test_myfunc(id, user):
    # Do something
    print(user)

    # Run this only after the last param which would be after (2, 'John')
    print('All done!')
```

I can run a conditional which checks for the value of `param` but I was just wondering if pytest has a way for this.

Comment: Can't you clean after each test ? That's a cleaner way to do it

Comment: For this test I can't since each test builds on the previous one. The test writes to Redis so the data is stored for the next test to use.

Comment: You have a specific class to run them : a setup method to write data, then tests on them, them a cleanup method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to perform this logic within a pytest hook, specifically the [`pytest_runtest_teardown`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_teardown) hook.

Assuming your test looks like the following,

```
import pytest

param = [(1, 'James'), (2, 'John')]
@pytest.mark.parametrize('id, user', param)
def test_myfunc(id, user):
    print(f"Iteration number {id}")
```

In the root of your test folder, create a `conftest.py` file and place the following,

```
func_of_interest = "test_myfunc"

def pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem):
    curr_name = item.function.__qualname__
    # check to see it is the function we want
    if curr_name == func_of_interest:
        # check to see if there are any more functions after this one
        if nextitem is not None:
            next_name = nextitem.function.__qualname__
        else:
            next_name = "random_name"
        # check to see if the next item is a different function
        if curr_name != next_name:
            print("\nPerform some teardown once")
```

Then when we run it, it produces the following output,

```
===================================== test session starts ======================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ***
collected 2 items                                                                              

test_grab.py::test_myfunc[1-James] Iteration number 1
PASSED
test_grab.py::test_myfunc[2-John] Iteration number 2
PASSED
Perform some teardown once
```

As we can see, the teardown logic was called exactly once, after the final iteration of the test call.

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't know about pytest hooks. Is there a list of hooks somewhere?

Comment: yes, all the hooks can be found --> https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#hooks